# How to Iterate through HashMap in MyBatis foreach?

Tags: java, sql, foreach, mybatis

I'm trying to produce a sql which is as below in mybatis.

```
SELECT COL_C
FROM TBLE_1
WHERE (COL_A, COL_B) in ( ('kp','kar'),('srt','sach'));
```

And my input parameter type is HashMap. Now How do I generate SQL from mapper xml file. The below code throws exception saying map evaluated to null.

```
<select id="selectCOLC" parameterType="java.util.HashMap" resultType="String">
    SELECT COL_C
    FROM TBLE_1
    WHERE (COL_A, COL_B) in 
    <foreach item="item" collection="#{map.keySet()}" open="((" separator="),(" close="))">
        #{item},#{item.get(item)}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

One of the other approach is to create a class with key value fields, create a list of object and then pass the `parameterType` as `list` which would look like following.

```
<select id="selectCOLC" parameterType="list" resultType="String">
        SELECT COL_C
        FROM TBLE_1
        WHERE (COL_A, COL_B) in 
        <foreach item="item" collection="list" open="((" separator="),(" close="))">
            #{item.getKey()},#{item.getVal()}
        </foreach>
    </select>
```

But is there any way to my mapper work for the first approach? other than changing the query to union

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**This solution doesn't work since version 3.2 - see more in [Issue #208](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/208) !**

Finally I've the solution for HashMap

I Should use `entrySet()` in order to make it iteratable

```
<select id="selectCOLC" parameterType="map" resultType="kpMap">
    SELECT COL_C
    FROM TBLE_1
    WHERE (COL_A, COL_B) in 
    <foreach item="item" collection="entries.entrySet()" open="((" separator="),(" close="))">
        #{item.key},#{item.value}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

One more Isue I was facing parameter name was not getting injected, Hence added `@Param` annotation

Hence mapper interface looks like below.

```
List<TblData> selectCOLC(@Param("entries")
            HashMap<String, String> entries)
```

Comment: **BEWARE: This ways is broken since version 3.2.x**: - version 3.2.x has direct support for a map [Issue #709](https://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=709) with _<foreach item="value" index="key" collection="map">_ and it must be rewritten to this new form - see [Issue #208](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/208) or @foghost solution

Comment: @MichalBernhard Can you please post your own answer? That will help further visitors a lot.

Comment: I posted one valid for my batis 3.5

Comment: @MichalBernhard I am using 3.2.x so how exactly i should use map values. It's still not clear from Issue #208 .Should I write #{value()}

Comment: @RujutaS solution from user  "Arcones" below does not work ? Arcones answer link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57265950/70786

Answer (score 17):

this is an example in my project and it works fine

```
<select id="getObject" parameterType="Map" resultType="hashmap">    
    select * from TABL where 
    <foreach  collection="dataMap"  index="key" item="value"  open=""  separator=" and "  close="">
        #{key}=#{value}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

Comment: this works only since version 3.2.x (see [Issue #709](https://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=709)

Comment: important distinction is that for List or Array the ```index``` indeed works as _index of the element_ but for a Map ```index``` becomes the key instead see: https://developpaper.com/mybatis-loop-foreach/

Answer (score 4):

As a user of mybatis 3.5, I came through this.

Unfortunately, none of the solutions posted here worked for me but this does:

```
<foreach collection="_parameter.entrySet()" index="key" item="element" separator=",">
    MY_COLUMN = #{key} AND MY_OTHER_COLUMN = #{element}
</foreach>
```

So, in my case **`collection="_parameter.entrySet()"`** did the trick!

Moreover, **none** specification regarding the *parameterType* was needed.

Comment: It worked for me as well. I am using spring-boot with mybatis.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example mybatis is looking for an entry in the parameterMap with the key "map". I suspect that you are actually trying to iterate the key set of the parameterMap. If you nested the map within the parameter map using the key "map" it should work.

In the second example you should just be able to pass the HashMap.entrySet() which provides a getKey and getValue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example.

```xml
<foreach index="key" item="value" collection="your_map_collection">
    #{key} = #{value}
</foreach>
```

> When using a Map (or Collection of Map.Entry objects), index will be the key object and item will be the value object.
> https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#foreach