# MyBatis iterate hashmap with foreach

Tags: mybatis

I have a small problem with MyBatis. I'm trying to iterate over a Hashmap but it seems, that MyBatis is not able to do it. The name of the Hshmap is serviceMap. Here is the code of the MyBatis foreach:

```
<foreach item="item" index="key" collection="serviceMap"  open="(" separator="or" close=")">
                (upper(p.ENDPOINT) like upper(#{key})
                and
                upper(p.ENDPOINT_OPERATION) like upper(#item))
</foreach>
```

The exception is:

```
org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error evaluating expression 'serviceMap'. Return value ({vehicle=register}) was not iterable.
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.dynamic.ExpressionEvaluator.evaluateIterable(ExpressionEvaluator.java:59)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.dynamic.ForEachSqlNode.apply(ForEachSqlNode.java:51)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.dynamic.MixedSqlNode.apply(MixedSqlNode.java:29)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.dynamic.IfSqlNode.apply(IfSqlNode.java:31)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.dynamic.MixedSqlNode.apply(MixedSqlNode.java:29)
```

Is MyBatis simply not able to do it or did I make an mistake?

It would be really nice, if anybody can help me.

Thanks a lot!
Stefan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Iterate through HashMap in MyBatis foreach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388936/how-to-iterate-through-hashmap-in-mybatis-foreach)

Answer (score 2):

A HashMap is not iterable. [You need to iterate the entrySet.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap)

```
<foreach item="item" index="key" collection="serviceMap.entrySet"  open="(" separator="or" close=")">
            (upper(p.ENDPOINT) like upper(#{key})
            and
            upper(p.ENDPOINT_OPERATION) like upper(#item))
```

Comment: this answer is deprecated if you're using mybatis version 3.2.x or higher. See this answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23534989/10376405

Answer (score 0):

```
<foreach item="item" index="key" collection="serviceMap.entrySet()" open="((" separator="),(" close="))">
                (upper(p.ENDPOINT) like upper(#{item.key})
                and
                upper(p.ENDPOINT_OPERATION) like upper(#item.value))
</foreach>
```

Use the exact hashmap mechanism