# MyBatis Issue with IN Condition <foreach with List inside a Map

Tags: java, mybatis

I have to build a IN condition using MyBatis where have to pass a list of `PARENT_VALUES` to be obtained based on the foreach loop below....

I tried but unable to resolve this. I am not sure if

Values Passed are:

```
Map input = new HashMap();
input.put("somedata");
List<String> inConditionList = new ArrayList<String>();
inConditionList.add("P1");
inConditionList.add("P2");
input.put(inConditionList);
sqlSessionTemplate.selectList("getNameAgeDetails", input);
```

**Required SQL:**

```
 SELECT P.NAME, P.AGE
   FROM PERSON_DETAILS P
   WHERE SOMECOLUMN is NULL AND DATA IN
   (SELECT DATA FROM PARENT_TABLE WHERE PARENT_VALUE IN ("P1, "P2"))
 ORDER BY P.NAME
  FETCH FIRST 10 ROW ONLY
```

**MyBatis Mapper SQL:**

```
<select id="getNameAgeDetails" parameterType="map" resultMap="someResultMap">
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT P.NAME, P.AGE
        FROM PERSON_DETAILS P
        WHERE
         SOMECOLUMN is NULL
        AND DATA IN
          (SELECT DATA
          FROM PARENT_TABLE
          WHERE PARENT_VALUE IN 
         <FOREACH item="item"  index="index" collection="list" separator="," open="(" close=")"> 
                ${item}
            </FOREACH>  
          )
          ORDER BY P.NAME
          FETCH 
            FIRST 10 ROW ONLY 
    ]]>
  </select>
```

Below is the Error I am getting when I try to run my Unit TestCases:

```
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: SELECT P.NAME, P.AGE
            FROM PERSON_DETAILS P
            WHERE
             SOMECOLUMN is NULL
            AND DATA IN
              (SELECT DATA
              FROM PARENT_TABLE
              WHERE PARENT_VALUE IN <FOREACH item="item"  index="index" collection="list" separator="," open="(" close=")">                      ?              </FOREACH>             
### Cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=PARENT_VALUE IN 
            <foreach it;TION
          WHERE;<space>, DRIVER=3.63.75
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=PARENT_VALUE IN
```

Comment: Please Note:  I am not using prepared statements in the above #{item} was one of the trials which I tried but I still see failures.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388936/how-to-iterate-through-hashmap-in-mybatis-foreach, you can check this question

Comment: I looked at the above link earlier my case is different from what has been posted there...

Comment: Is foreach getting substituted? I guess since you are applying CDATA for whole statement, <foreach is skipped and whole statement is being used for query.

Comment: Thats correct foreach is not getting subtituted..I am not sure how to correct that..

Comment: Just remove CDATA tag its required when you are using xml tags such as <, > etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Select statement would like something like this

```
<select id="getNameAgeDetails" parameterType="map" resultMap="someResultMap">
        SELECT P.NAME, P.AGE
        FROM PERSON_DETAILS P
        WHERE
         SOMECOLUMN is NULL
        AND DATA IN
          (SELECT DATA
          FROM PARENT_TABLE
          WHERE PARENT_VALUE IN 
         <FOREACH item="item"  index="index" collection="list" separator="," open="(" close=")"> 
                ${item}
            </FOREACH>  
          )
          ORDER BY P.NAME
          FETCH 
            FIRST 10 ROW ONLY 
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Karthik Prasad and if you remove CDATA and have sth like

```
a_column>=6 AND b_column<10
```

you must do the XML escape just as below:

```
a_column &gt;= 6 AND b_column &lt; 10
```