# Mybatis foreach collection is a list in a map-parameter

Tags: java, jdbc, mybatis

I'm using mybatis 3.2.8 version.

Mapper.java

```
List<BuddyId> findBuddyIds(HashMap<String, Object> map);
```

xml

```
<select id="findBuddyIds" parameterType="map" resultMap="BuddyIdResultMap">
select * 
from seerid.buddyIds
where id REGEXP
<foreach collection="idSplits" item="item" index="index" open="'" close="'" separator="|">
    #{item}
</foreach>
</select>
```

Controller.java

```
HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();

map.put("idSplits", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(idSplits)));

buddyScanResult = seerIdDAO.findBuddyIds(map);
```

It will receive the following error.

> #### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Could not set parameter
>
> #### The error may exist in file [/Users/jylee/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/services/WEB-INF/classes/com/ohinc/services/seerid/mybatis/SeerIdMapper.xml]
>
> #### The error may involve com.ohinc.services.seerid.mybatis.SeerIdMapper.findBuddyIds-Inline
>
> #### The error occurred while setting parameters
>
> #### SQL: select *   from seerid.buddyIds  where id REGEXP   '     ?   |    ?   '
>
> #### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Could not set parameter ; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [null]; error code
>
> [0]; Could not set parameter; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: Could not set parameter] with root cause
>   org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.query.IllegalParameterException: No
>   '?' on that position  at
>   org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.query.MySQLParameterizedQuery.setParameter(MySQLParameterizedQuery.java:103)

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Please help me.

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388936/how-to-iterate-through-hashmap-in-mybatis-foreach/21757685#21757685?

Answer (score 2):

I found this problem, may be can solve this question.
you xml have a mistake:

```
<select id="findBuddyIds" parameterType="map" resultMap="BuddyIdResultMap">
select * 
from seerid.buddyIds
where id REGEXP
<foreach collection="idSplits" item="item" index="index" open="'" close="'" separator="|">
    ${item}
</foreach>
</select>
```

you should be use $ replace # in foreach.

[MyBatis Issue with IN Condition <foreach with List inside a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374677/mybatis-issue-with-in-condition-foreach-with-list-inside-a-map)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, this should work. You should be able to pass in a map with multiple key="parameterName" and value="parameterValue". And one of those map entries could be a list, like you're doing (that map entry has key="idSplits" and value=yourArrayList). some ideas:

1. Could you provide the definition of your BuddyIdResultMap (it has to be defined in your mybatis mappings to define which columns go to which data member and what type of objects get returned).
2. Can you check to be sure that the "idSplits" list is not empty or has funny elements in it?

   map.put("idSplits", new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(idSplits)));
3. To unblock you, you could pass in a POJO (Plain Old Java Object) with one data member for each parameter you need to pass to the mapper. And one data member for the list. Like this:

BuddyDTO.java:

```
public class BuddyDTO implements Serializable {
  protected String someDataMember = null;
  protected List<String> idSplits= null;
// insert getter and setters here for data members and idSplits
}
```

Mapper.java

```
List<BuddyId> findBuddyIds(BuddyDTO dto);
```

xml

```
<select id="findBuddyIds" parameterType="BuddyDTO" resultMap="BuddyIdResultMap">
select * 
from seerid.buddyIds -- I'm guessing seerid is your schema name?
where id REGEXP
<foreach collection="idSplits" item="item" index="index" open="'" close="'" separator="|">
    #{item}
</foreach>
</select>
```

Controller.java

```
BuddyDTO dto = new BuddyDTO();
dto.setIdSplits( new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(idSplits))) );
buddyScanResult = seerIdDAO.findBuddyIds(dto);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="findBuddyIds" parameterType="map" resultMap="BuddyIdResultMap">
select * 
from seerid.buddyIds
where id REGEXP
<trim prefix="(" prefixOverrides=" " suffixOverrides=" " suffix=")">
    <foreach collection="idSplits" index="index" item="item" open="'" separator="|" close="'">^${item}</foreach>
</trim>
</select>
```

I'm using mybatis 3.4.2 version.