# How to get a specific Object from HashMap in MyBatis foreach?

Tags: java, foreach, mybatis

How can I get a specific object in a MyBatis foreach loop? I have written the following code:

```
<select id="getResult" resultMap="myResultMap" parameterType="java.util.HashMap">

    SELECT a.myselectfield_1, a.myselectfield_2                      
    FROM   ${mySchema}.test_a a    
    WHERE  a.field_x = 007
     AND   a.test_b IN 
             <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="#{map.get('myItems')}" open="(" separator="," close=")">
                #{item}         
            </foreach>
    ORDER BY a.myselectfield_1

</select>
```

This is the Java HashMap, which is relevant for the SQL Statement:

```
HashMap<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
myMap.put("mySchema", mySchema);
myMap.put("myItems", myArrayList);
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error querying database. Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException: target is null for method get
```

How can I read a specific value from a Java HashMap in MyBatis foreach? I´m using Version 1.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need use the get method for access the map element, you can write simply collection="myItems" or collection="map.myItems"in the foreach tag, depends on the way you had defined your mapper interface (the latter assumes that you used the @Param("map") annotation).

Comment: sorry, but your solution doesn´t work correctly. I get the same error message !

Answer (score 0):

you should be use $ replace # in foreach.

more information can see:

[Mybatis foreach collection is a list in a map-parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296265/mybatis-foreach-collection-is-a-list-in-a-map-parameter/36467388#36467388)

[MyBatis Issue with IN Condition <foreach with List inside a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374677/mybatis-issue-with-in-condition-foreach-with-list-inside-a-map)