# Mybatis statement with Map parameterType, how to refer to Map directly?

Tags: mybatis

I am passing a Map of parameters into a Mybatis select template:

```
 <select id="summary" parameterType="java.util.Map" resultMap='baseMap'>
...
```

The Map values have different types (String, Integer, Boolean) and I can refer to them in my query by key (String), e.g.:

```
where user_id = ${user_id}
```

So, in order to achieve this it would seem that the Mybatis framework/OGNL calls the Map's `get()` method, eg: `get("user_id")`

Is it possible to refer to the Map itself in order to call a different method on the Map itself as part of an OGNL clause? I can't figure out how to refer to the parameter map itself at all.

NOTE: I know that `parameterMap` is deprecated, but I am not averse to using it if it's the only way

Comment: I guess this will help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388936/how-to-iterate-through-hashmap-in-mybatis-foreach I'm passing Hashmap here

Comment: hmm, close... but I'm using sqlSession.selectList, rather than a mapper interface and therefore no named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There is an (alas undocumented) `_parameter` key in MyBatis' mapping context that gives you access to the input parameter of your statement. This should allow you access to the `Map` itself.

You can find more information in this MyBatis [issue](https://web.archive.org/web/20120418052758/http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=245) or in this [post](http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/Check-if-parameter-exists-td3926343.html).