# how to use ? mybatis parameterType is map and the map have a list

Tags: mybatis

the code like this 
how to use ? mybatis parameterType is map and the map have a list

```
Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
List list = new arrayList();
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
map.put("category", list)

service.updateByList(map)

   //xml like this
   <update id="updateByList" parameterType="java.util.Map">
        update hs_esl
        set
        category = #{?}
        where id in
        <foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" open="(" separator=","
     close=")">
            (#{?})
        </foreach>
   </update>
```

Comment: What are the keys in map?

Comment: the map only one data

Comment: one key and one list in map or another way to solution

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a case were you have a multiple set for same column. Hence hashMap is of no use I believe. Therefore you can create a object having field category and list like below.

**KPData.java**
    public class KPData {

```
    private String category;
    private List<Integer> sal;

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public List<Integer> getSal() {
        if (sal == null) {
            return new ArrayList<Integer>();
        } else {
            return sal;
        }
    }

}
```

Your sqlmap file would look like

```
<update id="setKP1" parameterType="kPData">

        update KPDATA
            set CATEGORY= #{kp1.category}
            where SAL in
            <foreach item="item1" index="index" collection="kp1.sal" open="("
                separator="," close=")">
                #{item1}
            </foreach>
</update>
```

And your interface file

public void setKP1(final @Param("kp1")KPData kp1) throws Exception;

If you still want to go for using hashmap please refer the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388936/how-to-iterate-through-hashmap-in-mybatis-foreach)