# Lists in MyBatis 'IN' clause

Tags: java, mysql, xml, mybatis, in-clause

How can I pass an Integer List to MyBatis XML, to be used in an in clause in my MySQL query?

I am using Java 7, MySQL 5.6 DB and MyBatis 3.0.4 with queries in a `mapper-xml` file.

Presently, I am converting this list of integers to a string, and using string substitution (`${}` operator) to put the values in the 'IN' clause - while it works as expected, this approach leaves the parameter vulnerable to Injection.

I have tried using a `<foreach>` element, but I am not able to figure out what attributes to specify.

**Below is a sample Java code :**

```
public List<Stripper> getStripperDetails(String club, List<Integer> stripperIds) {
        Map<String, Object> input = new HashMap<>();
        input.put("club", club);
        input.put("stripperIds", stripperIds);
        return stripClubMapper.getStripperDetails(input);
}
```

**Mapper xml :**

```
<select id="getStripperDetails" parameterType="java.util.HashMap" resultMap="StripperMap">
    SELECT STRIPPER_ID, STAGE_NAME, REAL_NAME, CLUB FROM EXOTIC_DANCERS WHERE CLUB = #{club} AND STRIPPER_ID IN     
    <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="stripperIds" open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{index}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

I am not able to figure out what attributes to specify for the `<foreach>` element - I keep running into a NullPointerException for the value at #{index}.

Can you please help me understand the correct usage of the `<foreach>` element?

Edit :

@10086 ,

Below is the stack trace :

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
### The error may involve com.stripclub.mapper.stripClubMapper.getStripperDetails-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:67) ~[mybatis-spring-1.0.0-RC3.jar:1.0.0-RC3]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:345) ~[mybatis-spring-1.0.0-RC3.jar:1.0.0-RC3]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy208.selectList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:193) ~[mybatis-spring-1.0.0-RC3.jar:1.0.0-RC3]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForList(MapperMethod.java:85) ~[mybatis-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:65) ~[mybatis-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:38) ~[mybatis-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy209.getTransactionIds(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: I have checked a few related questions such as [**this one**] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388936/how-to-iterate-through-hashmap-in-mybatis-foreach?lq=1) , but I am not able to figure out what to specify for the foreach attributes. Below is a sample from the [**dtd**](http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd).


`<!ELEMENT foreach (#PCDATA | include | trim | where | set | foreach | choose | if | bind)*>

<!ATTLIST foreach
collection CDATA #REQUIRED
item CDATA #IMPLIED
index CDATA #IMPLIED
open CDATA #IMPLIED
close CDATA #IMPLIED
separator CDATA #IMPLIED
>`

Comment: Is your stripperIds in map null or empty?

Comment: Nope, stripperIds is not null/empty, it has values.

Comment: OK, could you please post full stack exception information?

Comment: Hi @10086 , attached the stack trace info to the question. I know I am messing up the attribute values for the foreach tag, can you pls help me figure out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Obviously, this is a NPE error, as stack exception printed, error occurred when setting parameter, so check if two values in the map is `null` or not, and is there null element in `stripperIds`, and why do you set `#{index}` in `foreach`?

Comment: Nope, none of the elements in the map are null. I am presently using the ${} expression to create dynamic queries (Converting the stripperIds list to a list of string and substituting with ${stripperIds}), but this leaves the query open to injection. 

I want to use the #{} so that mybatis will execute this as  a prepared statement, and I want to avoid the explicit conversion from list of Integer to string in my code. The issue is that I am not able to figure out what values to provide for the foreach tag attributes so that I can directly pass my list in a param map, to be used in the query.

Comment: #{index} - No reason in particular,  because I tried putting other place holders related to  the list and it wouldn't work

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The value specified by the item attribute should be used inside the foreach tag, when used with Lists. Use as below :

```
    <foreach item="sId" collection="stripperIds" separator="," open="(" close=")">
        #{sId}
    </foreach>
```

The index attibute is not mandatory, when using a List. Refer the MyBatis docs section for more info, or check out the DTD - http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd for more info about the parameters :

```
    <!ELEMENT foreach (#PCDATA | include | trim | where | set | foreach | choose | if | bind)*>
    <!ATTLIST foreach
    collection CDATA #REQUIRED
    item CDATA #IMPLIED
    index CDATA #IMPLIED
    open CDATA #IMPLIED
    close CDATA #IMPLIED
    separator CDATA #IMPLIED
    >
```

Also, lists of objects can be accessed in foreach as below. You would typically use this for INSERT/UPDATE statements :

Sample bean :

```
public class StripperBean {

    public StripperBean(int stripperID, String stripperName, String realName) {
        this.stripperID = stripperID;
        this.stripperName = stripperName;
        this.realName = realName;
    }

    private int stripperID; 
    private String stripperName;
    private String realName;        

    public int getStripperID() {
        return stripperID;
    }
    public void setStripperID(int stripperID) {
        this.stripperID = stripperID;
    }
    public String getStripperName() {
        return stripperName;
    }
    public void setStripperName(String stripperName) {
        this.stripperName = stripperName;
    }
    public String getRealName() {
        return realName;
    }
    public void setRealName(String realName) {
        this.realName = realName;
    }       
}
```

In your implementation :

```
    Map<String, Object> input = new HashMap<>();
    input.put("club", club);
    List<StripperBean> strippers = new ArrayList<>();
    strippers.add(new StripperBean(1,"Ashley", "Jean Grey"));
    strippers.add(new StripperBean(2,"Candice","Diana Prince"));
    strippers.add(new StripperBean(3,"Cristal","Lara Croft"));        
    input.put("strippers", strippers);
    return stripClubMapper.saveStripperDetails(input);
```

In the mapper xml :

```
    <insert id="saveStripperDetails">
        INSERT INTO EXOTIC_DANCERS (STRIPPER_ID, STAGE_NAME, REAL_NAME)
        VALUES
        <foreach item="stripper" collection="input" separator=",">
            (#{stripper.stripperID},
            #{stripper.stripperName},
            #{stripper.realName})
        </foreach>
    </select>
```

Nice question BTW :)

Answer (score 12):

Using annotation should be easier

```
@Select({
        "<script>", "select", " * ", "FROM TABLE",
        "WHERE  CONDITION IN  " +
        "<foreach item='item' index='index' collection='list' open='(' separator=',' close=')'> #{item} </foreach>" +
        "</script>"  })
         @Results({ })
        List<POJO> selectByKeys(@Param("list") List<String> ids);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your xml should be like this:

```
<foreach item="item" index="index" collection="stripperIds" open="(" separator="," close=")">
    #{item}
</foreach>
```

When using a Map (or Collection of Map.Entry objects), index will be the key object and item will be the value object.

You can reference [here](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html) for the details. You will have a solid understanding about the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

your input is a map. so you need to resolve stripperIds from input before directly calling stripperIds.