# How to write XML MyBatis query in case using list of strings in parameters (has calling function in per String item)?

Tags: java, mariadb, mybatis

I am use MariaDB 10.x , MyBatis, Spring Boot 2.x , Java 8 . I need write query.

I have 2 functions:

```
function UuidFromBin

RETURN LCASE(CONCAT_WS('-',
    HEX(SUBSTR(_bin, 5, 4)),
    HEX(SUBSTR(_bin, 3, 2)),
    HEX(SUBSTR(_bin, 1, 2)),
    HEX(SUBSTR(_bin, 9, 2)),
    HEX(SUBSTR(_bin, 11))
)
```

```
function uuidToBin

RETURN UNHEX(CONCAT(
    SUBSTR(_uuid, 15, 4),
    SUBSTR(_uuid, 10, 4),
    SUBSTR(_uuid, 1, 8),
    SUBSTR(_uuid, 20, 4),
    SUBSTR(_uuid, 25)
)
```

datatype of field `po.id` and `po.shop_id` are binary.

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("8766103-c1e7-4189-940b-3aeeeef041db", "00000000-0000-3100--0000-00000000");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("00000000-0000-3100--0000-00000000" , "00000000-0000-3100--0000-00000002");
```

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    UuidFromBin(po.shop_id) AS shop_id,
    po.name
    po.state
FROM product_offering po
WHERE po.id IN (UuidToBin('8766103-c1e7-4189-940b-3aeeeef041db'), UuidToBin('00000000-0000-3100--0000-00000000')) -- list1
AND po.shop_id IN (UuidToBin('00000000-0000-3100--0000-00000000'), UuidToBin('00000000-0000-3100--0000-00000002')) -- list2
```

How to write XML MyBatis query in case using list of strings in parameters?

Addition information: I see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44022017/3728901 , I have difficult with call `UuidToBin` in per item of String list.

Comment: Two questions: 1) what's the column type of `shop_id`?  2) can you use `java.util.UUID` instead of `String`?

Comment: 1) db: MariaDB 10.x . Column type of `shop_id` is binary. 2) You maybe suggest me a good practices, but in my case, for safety, let follow my previous steps. (you can add more arround information about it.) thank you

Comment: If you use `String`, it's a text book usage of [`<foreach  />`](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#foreach).  e.g. `<foreach item="s" collection="list1" separator="," open="(" close=")">UuidToBin(#{s})</foreach>`

Comment: Thank you very much! I know you is key MyBatis' commiter. I will try to follow your suggestion with UUID later.

Comment: YW! It's just that other committers are busier lately. ;D  Using `java.util.UUID` might make the statement simpler because you can use type handler. See this [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/0194194873963d263544d314a76f84625e208992/so-60613619) if you are interested. Note that your type handler may need to call `setBytes()`/`getBytes()` instead. You can do the 'rearranging', too. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29836273/1261766) may help. If you have any difficulty, please update the question with the details.