# dynamic update query mybatis mapper

Tags: java, mybatis, mapper

I'm trying to do create a mybatis generic update method.

I have a service with this functionality:

```
Map<String, Object> map = convertObjectToMapforUpdate(entity, UPDATE);
mapper.update(tableName, map, identifier);
```

where String is the parameter attribute and Object is the value.

And an interface like this:

```
void update(@Param("tableName") String tableName, @Param("map") Map<String, Object> map, @Param("identifier") long identifier);
```

I'm trying to define a generic update with mybatis using mapper xml file like this:

```
<update id="update" parameterType="java.util.HashMap">
    UPDATE ${tableName}
    SET <foreach item="key" collection="map" index="index" separator=", ">
            ${key} = #{key}
        </foreach>
    WHERE identifier = #{identifier}
</update>
```

I tried lots of options but none of them are working. I tried using a List instead of a HashMap, I tried using the specific Object as a parameterType but any of them worked.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: Have you tried solutions described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388936/how-to-iterate-through-hashmap-in-mybatis-foreach ? You question is basically a duplicate of that question. If it is not provide more details regarding what is not working, what errors you get etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Roman. It helped a lot. I'm sorry to duplicate the question because I wasted 3 days looking for a solution and nothing found. Please, mark this question as duplicated an refer to Roman's link. Thank you